# scroll handler to be executed once per second

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I have a handler written for window scroll

```
$(window)
    .scroll(
        _.debounce(function(e) {
            /* <some logic here to calculate the scrollVar> */
            $this.scrollTo(getNextY(scrollVar, 'down'), 1000); //animates the scroll for 1000 ms

        }, 1000)
    );
```

The problem here is underscore's debounce executes the scroll handler at the end of 1000ms, so the scroll animation happens after a delay of 1000ms.

Is there a way or a predefined function in underscore that runs the handler first and doesnt allow further scroll event to be triggered for 1000ms(debounce duration).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: no, a handler function can't stop new event invocations, but you could use an external boolean switch or something...

Comment: ya. but thats y debounce is there right? I think I found the answer, in the debounce doc theres a third argument(boolean) to specify whether to run the actual function in the leading edge or trailing edge. Let me try. Thanks anyways..